# MySQL relationships vs performance

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I create relationships between tables of my databases.

I have read that indexes slow the write queries and that unused indexes are useless.

To do a relationship it is required that a column be a foreign key (I am using InnoDb) so that I can link it to another table's primary key.

Some of these indexes will never be used on a search query and they are only used for the relationship purpose.

I'm using PHP and Yii Framework so all queries and writes are code based and checked for integrity (unique, exists, etc).

Will I really benefit from these relationships if it can slow down my queries in the future in a big data context?

Comment: Without a description of your tables and queries, your question is purely speculative.  I can say that relational databases are used effectively for "big data" problems, so I guess relationships and indexes work well-enough in practice, at least sometimes.

Comment: The indexes might never be used in a query but they will in a JOIN statement. Indexing is a balancing act. It slows down writes yes but only in small amounts. Indexes speeds up reads massively. I have seen queries go down from hours to seconds. So they are crucial to a good database. Just like chocolate if you eat too much you can get sick. Same with indexes.

Comment: hey there. I edited your question to improve the grammar and make it somewhat more readable, removing some noisy text in the meantime. You should definitely think about editing your question again with links showing *where* you have read what you mention :)

Comment: Indexes DO slow down writes but are not 'useless'. They do help speed up your selects.You will only really notice write performance degrade of large tables. So you need to understand where you need the speed - in saving data, or retrieving it.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Sorry for the mess, English is not my main language and i'm not perfect in its grammar but i try my best. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Thanks for all the others comments, very usefull to me and explain alot. Another question i have about the indexes (i forgot to ask) is if a column (tinyint(1)) just for save a 0 or 1 like active or not worth be an index? For exemple i wan't to select all active users, or active items or even order that column. Somewhere in the past i have read that 0 or 1 column does not benefit from a index, is that true?

Comment: I think it is only worth an index if you have less than 1% of all rows containing an 1 and the rest contains a zero (or the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

This highly depends on the queries you run on your tables.

First: Yes, every index slows down the write operation, since the new data has to be added at the right place (indexes are sorted).
If the index is used, this is not a problem, since it highly speeds up the look up operations.

But lets have a look at an example:
Lets say you have a table `data1(id1,id2,some_text)` and one table `data2(id1,some_more_text)`. And lets say you have the index `(id2,id1)` on `data1` and the index `id1` on `data2`. Here you would have to add an index `id1` on `data1` to add an relationship between `data1` and `data2`. You can improve this by changing the index `(id2, id1)` to `(id1,id2)`. Since indexes in MySQL are prefix indexes, you can now use `(id1,id2)` also as an index `id1` and so use it for the foreign key.
But you also loose the ability to use the index for look ups that only use the field `id2`, since it is no prefix of an index any more.

If you add indexes you should consider the following:

- What are the queries I run on this table?
  If you filter by multiple columns, you should put them in one index (MySQL only uses one index per table and query)
- Do I need a foreign key?
  Foreign keys are very useful to make the database take care about your data integrity. But you should also try to use existing indexes to setup an relationship, maybe by changing the order of an multi-column index, if possible.

Comment: "MySQL only uses one index per table and query" Where did you get that piece of rubbish information? Maybe back around 4.3 or something but definitely not now.

Comment: @DavidSoussan I understand [the third last point](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html) the way, that the optimizer chooses *one* index which promises the least number of rows, depending on the actual query. Maybe I wrote it a little confusing?

Comment: MySQL chooses the INDEXES that will best optimise the query and return the least number of rows from step to step. This is nothing like "only using 1 index". That manual entry is just a starting point for understanding the behaviour of the query optimiser and indexes. Real understanding takes years. In the mean time, get the mysql workbench which provides very good graphical representations of EXPLAIN output. All anyone needs to know is that without indexes you get table scans and they are muder on your performance.

Comment: @DavidSoussan Can you provide a link where I can read about that? This is the first time I read, that MySQL uses more than one index per table. If MySQL can use more than one index at the same time, why would someone use (non unique) multi column indexes, instead of using an index for each column separately?

Comment: @DavidSoussan Interesting, I always thought that mysql would use only 1 index always. Isn't that why EXPLAIN gives you a `possible_keys` column, and a `key` column which tells you waht the optimizer used? I mean, even MariaDB's Explain Analyzer tool (https://mariadb.org/explain_analyzer/analyze/) describes that column as "The name of the key that is used to retrieve rows", which to me sounds like a single key

Comment: Lots of confusion here. I think MySQL always choose the best path to get a result and go from index to index for best performance. But the question is more relationships based.

Comment: @TiagoConceição I think this discussion has not that much to do with your question, but it is interesting. Maybe my answer helps you anyway.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Yes that true but its interesting and all comments are welcome. Also see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633520/mysql-relationships-vs-performance/30633776?noredirect=1#comment49374538_30633520